# Formatting a 'duration' column in the query

Tags: sql

I have a column 'Duration' it holds the time the therapist spent with the client.
This is always entered as minutes so if the time was 3 hours it is entered as 180. I would like to set this in the query as 3.
This is how it is reporting from a canned report: Total duration time is the entered column, it is
defined as int,null. I would like to make this calculation and formatiing, in the sql for the shown column 'total duration'.

```
total_duration_num  total_duration
10                    0:10
120                   2:00
30                    0:30
5                     0:05
60                    1:00
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

One means of achieving this is to use:

- the `floor` function to round down when dividing the minutes by 60 (for whole hours)
- the `mod` function to get the remaining number of minutes after putting however many can fit into "whole" 60-minute hours
- the `lpad` function to put a leading zero before that number of minutes, if <10, so that you see :05 rather than :5 for example

The query would look like this:

```
select    duration,
          concat( floor(duration/60) , ':' , lpad(mod(duration,60),2,'0') ) as hrs_mins
from      duration_table;
```

This is a demonstration:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a52b6c/1/0